# Youtube API - Get youtube-trends via Json, possible?

Tags: json, youtube-api

is it possible to get the Youtube Trends http://feeds.feedburner.com/youtube-trends via json?

**Youtube GDATA**
http://gdata.youtube.com/demo/index.html

**Example json link**
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/most_recent?alt=json

**Did not work**
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/youtube_trends?alt=json
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/youtube-trends?alt=json

Thanks in advance!
Peter

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are looking for the Trending videos on YouTube, you can find that feed at:

https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/on_the_web?alt=json

It is [described as](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/reference.html#Standard_feeds):

> This feed lists trending videos as
>   seen on [YouTube Trends](http://youtube-trends.blogspot.com/), which surfaces
>   popular videos as their popularity is
>   increasing and also analyzes broader
>   trends developing within the YouTube
>   community. This feed is available as
>   an experimental feature.

What you are referencing are blog posts based on that feed, as seen on [here](http://youtube-trends.blogspot.com/).

Comment: No longer available, any other ways?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need an API key.
Then, Just paste the following link into a web browser and then right-click --> save as JSON

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=contentDetails&chart=mostPopular&regionCode=lk&key= {Your API key}

{Your API key} - Your personal API key can get from - https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started

This question is already answered here

[Youtube API - Getting trending videos for a specific keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36925683/youtube-api-getting-trending-videos-for-a-specific-keyword/36934269)