# Getting results from youtube trends hot videos with php curl

Tags: php, curl, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I want to get the results from youtube trends hot videos : 
[http://www.google.com.tr/trends/hotvideos#geo=CA&hvsm=1](http://www.google.com/trends/hotvideos#geo=CA&hvsm=1&hvd=20150320)
I am using curl.

```
function cek($ursa){
    $useragent  = 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)';
    $referer    = 'http://www.google.com/';
    $ch = curl_init();
    $zaman = 0;
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $ursa);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $zaman);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $referer);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 5);
    $rmx = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $rmx;
 }
$html = cek("http://www.google.com.tr/trends/hotvideos#geo=CA&hvsm=1");   
echo $html;
```

When i get the page with curl i don't see video links in the page. 
How can i get them? I've looked on youtube api but couldn't find a way to get these results. Is there a way to get these results from Youtube api?

Comment: What is the result of the request ?

Comment: @Raptor : this website doesn't allows me to add it because the result is too long. Here is the result : https://justpaste.it/k5nq

Comment: Got it. I noticed that you're not using Youtube API. You should use the API instead of getting the HTML source code of the whole YouTube page.

Comment: Make sure you read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6424739/youtube-api-get-youtube-trends-via-json-possible) as well

Answer (score 0):

The videos do not appear because they are loaded with javascript, which is not executed by curl. I don't know about the youtube api, but to get the data from the website you will need to analyze the javascript it uses and replicate the requests it makes.

Comment: is there a way to get the page with javascript in curl? like it's browsing with the browser?

Comment: @r10 You could emulate a browser, but it should be easier to just view source, figure out what javascript is retrieving the videos, and translate that.

Comment: I'm not sure but i think this is the code they call as javascript : 
http://pastebin.com/57EtLjJy
When i request these urls, it's giving me the JS files. 
Do u have any sample which shows how i can get them running?

Comment: @r10 Java Rhino can execute javascript, but you'll need to simulate a browser to actually see the results.