# Youtube API - Getting trending videos for a specific keyword

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I need to fetch trending videos for a specific keyword with the Youtube API.

For example, videos that are trending for "Lebron James".

Can it be done via the Youtube API? Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

Trending Videos

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=contentDetails&chart=mostPopular&regionCode=IN&key=API_KEY

1.**part** : The part names that you can include in the parameter value are id, snippet, contentDetails, fileDetails, liveStreamingDetails, localizations, player, processingDetails, recordingDetails, statistics, status, suggestions, and topicDetails.

**chart** :The chart parameter identifies the chart that you want to retrieve. (string) like 'mostPopular'

**regionCode** :The parameter value is an ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 country code. (string)

**key** : Google Project API key

Comment: Thanks Ashish! What I need to do though is to fetch trending videos, as opposed to most popular ones. Can a 'trending' parameter be used, instead of 'mostPopular'?

Comment: 'mostPopular' seems to be the only chart available currently. See https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#parameters